# Server Error in '/' Application. - No Relevant Source Lines .NET FRAMEWORK 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, permissions, expression-blend

I started a Silverlight project in VS2010 Beta 2. Using parallels on my Mac and I´ve added this to the Web.Config to compile succesfully:

```
<runtime>
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

But the page loads with this Error and I searched a lot without success:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to 'Y:\test1\Application\tApplication.Web'.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: Y:\test1\Application\Application.Web\web.config    Line: 0

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.21006; ASP.NET Version:4.0.21006.1

Any Idea? Is a problem with Permissions? How can I fix this?

Thanks in Advance,

David V.

Answer (score 2):

You have to grant Full Control on the Security Tab (Right Click in the Folder and Properties)

Or simply you have to place your project in the root folder of the Windows Installation...

Remember I´m working with a Virtual Machine on my Mac.

Comment: David, I'm running visual studio with a vm on my mac and having the same issue. I tried to use your solution but failed. My project is created in the shared folder instead of the windows local disk, so I'm not able to access the "security tab" in properties. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a compatibility issue with Parallels.

Where is the web.config file?
What type of drive?

**EDIT**: [Parallels drive sharing uses network drives, which don't support file change notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856016/running-visual-studio-in-parallels-for-mac-problem-with-debugging-sites-sitting/911507#911507).

You need to run from a virtual drive.

Comment: The Drive is a Shared .psf (Y:\) but I granted its permissions through:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -m -ag 1.5 -url file://\\.psf/Parallels-VS2010/* FullTrust
---------------------------------

But when I re-open the project, VS2010 give me a Security Warning:
You Should Only Open Projects From a TrustWorthy Source
-------------------------
That´s why I have to add the following lines to the web.config (Located in the Web Folder of each project)
------------------------

<runtime>
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
</runtime>


.. Thanks


DV

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will helpful for you since I was troubling with this issue and just resolved with this.

Disable FCN:

- Open Regedit.exe (not RegEdt32!)
- Add a DWORD at HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET\FCNMode, with a value of '1'
- Add a DWORD at HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET\FCNMode, with a value of '1' (on 64-bit systems, dual entry is required)
- Reboot (iisreset may suffice, but some users have found a reboot neccessary)

For more details just go with this link http://imageresizing.net/docs/howto/avoid-network-limit

Answer (score 0):

What was happening to me was that the code wasn't being compiled because of being on a network drive. I switched the project to a local directory and then overwrote the old directory on the server and it works.

Comment: That should work or he could try changing the permissions on the network.

Answer (score 0):

More often than not it's down to human error with webconfig problems. This time, it's probably complaining that there is an **appsetting** declared with the same **key/name**, so check that all the appsetting have unique key/names.

A short (more like lazy) way of checking for duplicates is by hosting the web app in IIS, and accessing the **Application Settings** via the **Feature View Tab** for the project.

Bit late a response, but hopefully a reference to anyone who experiences this annoying problem in future.