# Running Visual Studio ASP.NET project on a Mac with Parallels 6

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, parallels, network-drive

I use Mac as my primary OS, but I often work on ASP.NET MVC projects. I want to use the same file system for them, and not virtual OS image.

The reason for that is because I want to integrate the projects with Mac OS (i.e. upload them to the server via Transmit, a Mac OS FTP app).

But the problem here is that ASP.NET can't really work with projects located on network drives. So when I try to run a site (either with VS 2010's built in web server or with IIS 7), I get

> Error Summary HTTP Error 500.19 -
>   Internal Server Error The requested
>   page cannot be accessed because the
>   related configuration data for the
>   page is invalid.

And this is a common mistake but no solution that I could find worked for me.

If I create a project on Parallel's virtual C:\ drive, everything works fine.

P.S. I hear that VMWare has better network drives support, but is it as smooth as Parallels? Parallels 6 runs extremely fast for me, and my Mac Mini doesn't even get warm with VS 2010 and several other Mac apps open.

P.P.S. I also heard about using DropBox and/or Windows Live Mesh. Is clouding a good idea in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an awful lot of pain for yourself if you want to do all this this just because you want to use a Mac FTP client to deploy your sites/applications.

Visual Studio 2010 contains Publishing tools which make deployment much easier (and are smarter) than just ftp. I suggest you have a play with them and then see if you still want to go down this dark, bumpy and dangerous path :-)

Comment: It's not only FTP. I also prefer Finder and having all my files in one place. Creating a copy on a virtual machine means more pain for me.

Comment: I can see, there's no solution... I'll just use VM's hard drive then.

Comment: I would say so. FYI in case you haven't seen this - this question has pretty much been asked before, albeit with a different focus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856016/running-visual-studio-in-parallels-for-mac-problem-with-debugging-sites-sitting

Comment: You know, working in Windows is not that bad :) I have 100% of the screen space used and .NET is about Windows, isn't it? So, yeah, I just moved my projects to virtual C:\ drive.

Comment: Its not bad. I'm doing my ASP.Net dev on a MacPro and, after 3+ years of working in Parallels bit the bullet a few months ago and installed bootcamp. Now dual-booting Windows 7 for work purposes. Its a lot better than Vista/XP and I've no complaints.

You can also the bootcamp install of Windows in Parallels too for those times when you just have to use a Mac but still need MS dev kit ;-)