# Run Webapp stored on network drive in Visualstudio

Tags: visual-studio, networking, web-applications, virtualbox, drive

Im going crazy! I hope you can help me with an advice.

Inside Virtualbox I do run a Windows Server 2008 R2. On this machine im trying to debug a webapplication inside Visualstudio 2010. the webbapplication is stored on a network drive. 
Well the network drive is truly a partition of my hdd. because of the shared folder the virtual machine recognize it like an network drive but in my opinion i doesnt matter to the actual problem.

When i try to start the applition a get an error like this:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file:
>   Failed to start monitoring changes to 'E:\Testing\In Work\5.1
>   SP1\SitefinityWebApp'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: E:\Testing\In Work\5.1
>   SP1\SitefinityWebApp\web.config    Line: 0
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18034

I allready tried get fulltrust to the application via caspol using the following:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CasPol.exe -m -ag 1 -url "file:////\\VBOXSVR\d_drive\Testing\In Work\5.1 SP1\SitefinityWebApp*" FullTrust -exclusive on
```

or this

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CasPol.exe -machine -addgroup All_Code -url "E:\Testing\In Work\*" FullTrust
```

but nothing helped!

Has anybody an solution?

p.s. 
if i run the same project on the virtual hdd it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that network drives can't be monitored by Windows for file changes like local drives can so in fact it matters where you put your source code so your WebApp can automagically reload it on changes - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/911507/2148786) a possible but maybe outdated solution is given.